# Serializer for nested objects on POST query

Tags: python, django

Im new to DRF and i have problem with a nested serializer. I cannot save/create the list of ingredients in recipe.

I'll start with **model.Recipe** that has a attribute ingredients

```
ingredients = models.ManyToManyField(Ingredient,
                                         through='IngredientInRecipe',
                                         blank=True)
```

**model.IngredientInRecipe** has the following attributes (i need through='IngredientInRecipe' because of the "amount" field)

```
class IngredientInRecipe(models.Model):
    recipe = models.ForeignKey(Recipe, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ingredient = models.ForeignKey(Ingredient, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6,
                                 decimal_places=1,
                                 validators=[MinValueValidator(1)]
                                 )
```

When sending a POST query to /recipes/ with data, i get the following errror

```
{
  "ingredients": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "amount": 10
    }
  ],
  "tags": [
      1,
      2
  ],
  "name": "Recipe 1",
  "text": "Recipe 1",
  "cooking_time": 1
  
}
```

**TypeError at /api/recipes/
Field 'id' expected a number but got (<IngredientInRecipe: IngredientInRecipe object (14)>, True).**

the **RecipeSerializer** looks like below and debug show that the problem is in
recipe_instance.ingredients.add(ingredient_in_recipe_instance)

```
class RecipeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Serializer for recipe objects"""

    author = UserSerializer(required=False)
    name = serializers.CharField(max_length=200, required=True)
    image = serializers.ImageField(required=False)
    ingredients = IngredientInRecipeSerializer(many=True)

    tags = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        many=True,
        queryset=Tag.objects.all()
    )

    def create(self, validated_data):
        tags_data = validated_data.pop('tags')
        ingredients_data = validated_data.pop('ingredients')
        recipe_instance = Recipe.objects.create(author=self.context['request'].user, **validated_data)
        for tag in tags_data:
            recipe_instance.tags.add(tag.id)

        for ingredient in ingredients_data:
            ingredient_instance = get_object_or_404(Ingredient,id=ingredient['id'])
            ingredient_in_recipe_instance = IngredientInRecipe.objects.get_or_create(ingredient=ingredient_instance,
                                                                                     amount=ingredient['amount'],
                                                                                     recipe = recipe_instance)
            recipe_instance.ingredients.add(ingredient_in_recipe_instance)
            
        return recipe_instance
```

**IngredientInRecipeSerializer** - any thoughts would be greate

```
class IngredientInRecipeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Serializer for ingredient in recipe objects"""
    
    id = serializers.IntegerField()
    amount = serializers.DecimalField(max_digits=6,
                                      decimal_places=1)
    name = serializers.StringRelatedField()
    measurement_unit = serializers.StringRelatedField()
    
    class Meta:
        model = IngredientInRecipe
        fields = (
            'id',
            'amount',
            'name',
            'measurement_unit',
        )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IngredientInRecipe.objects.get_or_create` returns a tuple of (object, created), not the object itself

Comment: changed to this
`code`
ingredient_in_recipe_instance = IngredientInRecipe.objects.create(ingredient=ingredient_instance,
                                                                                     amount=ingredient['amount'],
                                                                                     recipe = recipe_instance)
            recipe_instance.ingredients.add(ingredient_instance)
`code`

Comment: but if i try to add to ingredients -> ingredient_instance - it says that my model has no attribute "amount". That's fair , because my Ingredient model doest has it. Instead my Recipe model has the ingredients attrbute, but thgrou another table
`code`
ingredients = models.ManyToManyField(Ingredient,
                                         through='IngredientInRecipe',
                                         blank=True)
`code`